# matching the data vlaue when binding in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object

```
$scope.testing = "Mohan,Rahul,Kanal,Rajesh,Gokul,Ramesh" ;

<label>{{testing}}</label>
```

I want to check particular name like (Ramesh) is have or not in testing.

Comment: Please put a clear cut question else no will answer as they don't understand  your question.

Comment: @Mohan: Yesterday you have something different issue with same json.  Write your question with proper reference.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to transfer the testing string into an array. 
Here is the code:

```
<label>{{testing.split(',').indexOf("Ramesh")>=0}}</label>
```